# Modifying a string by passing a pointer to a void function

Tags: c, strings, beginner, pointers

Please explain the relationship between pointers and arrays.  In this [tutorial](http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/functions/pass_by_reference.aspx), they change `int c` by changing `*r` in the function.  How is that possible?

Also, please review my code for reversing a string.  The string variable belongs to the `main()` function, and I would like to pass a pointer to let the `strreverse()` function write to the string.  Does my code work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void strreverse(char *string)
{
 int i, len;
 char c;
 len=strlen(string);
 char string2[len+1];

 for(i=0; i<len; i++)
 {
  c=string[i];
  string2[len-i]=c;

 }
 string2[len+1]='\0';
 string=string2;
 //printf("%s\n", string); <-- this would work,but should be in main

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char str[256];
  printf("Type a String to reverse it.[max. 255 chars]\n");
  fgets(str, 255, stdin);
  strreverse(&str[0]);
  printf("%s", str);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that your code requires C99, but that's fine for now.

Comment: That was recommended in my books. Thanks for making my request readable!

Comment: I never really understand the point of adding command line arguments when it is not used in the program.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been put on hold. This site is for code reviews, and there are *plenty* of issues in this code for critique. (It fails the "you must post working code criterion", but a beginner who has made a good effort doesn't deserve to be turned away, I think.)

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I've compiled your code with C90 and it doesn't reverse the given string.

- `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` If you're not compiling from the command line with arguments to be used by the program, then `int main()` suffices.
- Passing argument by pointer is used when you want the value of the variable changed. Say I have a variable `int var` and a function `change(.)`, I want change to alter the value of `var`. If I declare change as `void change(int n)` and I call `change(var)`, function `change` will take a copy of `var` named `var` but it's only a copy, its address is different from the original `var`. Any change you make on copy `var` will not affect the original `var`. If i declare change as `void change(int* n)`, then change will only accept `int` pointers, I have to pass the address, `&var` into `change` as `change(&var)`. Now working on this address is exactly like working on the initial `var`.

To understand pointer-array relationship read [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29#C_arrays).

```
int array[5];      // Declares 5 contiguous integers 
int *ptr = array;  // Arrays can be used as pointers 
ptr[0] = 1;        // Pointers can be indexed with array syntax 
*(array + 1) = 2;  // Arrays can be dereferenced with pointer syntax 
*(1 + array) = 3;  // Pointer addition is commutative 
2[array] = 4;      // Subscript operator is commutative
```

Array names are not really pointers but can be used as pointers. Instead of  `strreverse(&str[0])`, you can do `strreverse(str)`. Same result.

You've passed argument as pointer but your code still fails, why?

- One thing to know about `fgets` is that unless there is an `[EOF][2]` which you can only get from an input file or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> if you run from the command line, `fgets` exits when the length argument is reached or it encounters a newline. In summary, `fgets` reads the newline as a character when you press enter key, increasing your desired length by 1. So if I had entered `"my string"` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, your variable `str` becomes `"my string\n"`.
- So you got the length of the string into `len`. The array `string` is zero-based, calling `string[len]` return the `char` after the desired last one. The last char is `string[len - 1]`.

You should have done this;

```
char string2[len];

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
  c=string[i];      //variable c is unimportant
  string2[len-i-1] = string[i];  //observe the -1, when i = 0, string2[len - 1] = string[0]
}
string2[len] ='\0';
```

Now that you're done reversing, you need to understand the implication of your next move.

```
string = string2;
```

`string` is a pointer, but that doesn't make it any less of a variable, it's a pointer variable, it also has an address. And if I declare a pointer variable to its address, that pointer will also have an address. Going back to what I said earlier, when you call `change(&var)`, a copy of the address of `var` is passed into the function, so when you change the value of this pointer, it no longer holds the address of var. You may think about dereferencing, like this

```
*string = *string2;
```

but this will only alter the first value of the array since `*string` is same as `string[0]`. The solution is to copy element by element.

```
for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
  string[i] = string2[i];
```

Now your string is reversed.

*Read this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) to understand how an array can be reversed faster.*

Comment: +1 thank you for this.  I'm awful at pointers, even though I don't have to worry too much about the raw ones in C++.  It never hurts to learn the fundamentals of C, either. :-) Your changes do work, by the way.

Comment: @Jamal I agree, pointers can be a pain in the ass but they force one to code carefully.

Comment: Right.  Still, for serious C++ applications, I'll just (learn) and stick with STL pointers.  I believe one of my few SO questions shows my earliest attempt at using *double* pointers.